On a Compose Multiplatform gradle plugin, how can I include desktop configuration?
I am making my first Compose Multiplatform app, I want to organise my codebase with multiple modules. To do that I am creating gradle plugins with build-logic, I found an article explaining how to do that for a CMM project (I had already done that for some Android projects) but it is for an Android and iOS project. I followed those steps anyway, but now Ican't find a way to include desktop configuration.
Has anyone done that or knows where I could find this info ?
To see the project's convention plugins, check this repository.

do you have github that show how you setup your convention plugin?

Yes, here : project
